# What is the native way to create a shortcut (.LNK file) from the Windows XP command line?

Tags: windows-xp, shortcut, command-prompt

### EDIT!

Sorry to change the question on everyone, but I am really just asking:

How do I create a shortcut (.LNK) file from the command line with as little outside help as possible?  I really don't want to run a VBscript or to download a program to do it for me.  Is it really **that** hard?

Thanks to everyone who provided exceptional answers when I didn't really know what I was asking yet!

---

The original title of this question was:

> Windows equivalent of Unix ln -s for
>   creating shortcuts from the command
>   line?

The original question text of this question was:

> On *nix, I can create a symbolic link
>   to a file very easily from the command
>   line using `ln -s`.
>
> How do I **natively** create a
>   shortcut to a file using the Windows
>   XP command prompt?
>
> <sub>Note: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file) is not the
>   approach I want to take.  I want to do
>   it the way Windows does it.  I want to
>   do it the right way.</sub>

Comment: I think you should restore your previous question, which has some useful answers, to help other that may have that question in the future. You should then start a new question about creating shortcuts from the command line.

Comment: And I think it really is that hard under XP. VBScript is your best option for a native Windows solution, if you really don't want to use a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.ss64.com/nt/shortcut.html
EDIT:
Sorry I deleted that. .. but that is an old NT command ... don't know if it active on XP.

Answer (score 5):

Windows XP and later has the `fsutil` command, which can create "hardlinks" to files.

See:

- [MSDN: Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006.aspx)
- [JSI Tip 10153: The Windows XP FSUTIL.EXE HARDLINK CREATE command](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/85206/jsi-tip-10153-the-windows-xp-fsutilexe-hardlink-create-command.html)

Comment: A hardlink is not a shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

XP doesn't have symlinks. On Vista, the command is mklink. Shortcuts are not symlinks.

Comment: shortcuts are files. symlinks are a different construct. There really is no comparison

Comment: Shortcuts are a file that Explorer knows how to parse; if I open a shortcut to a text file with Notepad, I get nonsense, not the text file the shortcut points to

Comment: In UNIX, symbolic links act equivalently to the item they link to unless you specifically request different behavior.  Windows shortcuts are not parsed in the file system layer, but in Explorer itself.  Thus, many programs *cannot* follow shortcuts.

Comment: XP *does* have symlinks, it's build into NTFS. That Microsoft chose not to expose this functionality says volumes IMO. See http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink for more information and an interface to create them.

Comment: @Matt, hard links != symlinks != junction points; hard links are completely different, junction points are similar but can't point to another filesystem (they have to point to something else in the same NTFS volume)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a native Windows call, but you should probably look into [Windows Sysinternals'  Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx). This is a very handy tool of good quality.

If you don't want to rely on external software, you should look at [kb205524](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205524) for native ways of creating junction points.

Answer (score 1):

I have a file called shortcut.exe on my system. Honestly, I have no idea where I got it. :-( But a quick search came up with the following website:

http://www.optimumx.com/download/#Shortcut

Maybe that will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

[`mklink`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) `link target`

Unfortunately, this only works on Vista/Server 2008 or newer.

Comment: This does not create a shortcut.

Comment: @StevenPenny When I answered the question, the question was "Windows equivalent of Unix ln -s for creating shortcuts from the command line?"

Comment: Well that is not the question now, so your answer is not appropriate.

Comment: @StevenPenny You realize that the answers from Magnus, Paul, Patrick, sig11, Loki, and rmeador are all also answering the same question I did and not the one that's currently in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Actually NTFS does support symbolic links.  See [Wikipedia NTFS_symbolic_link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: Yes, but only in Vista. Junction points and reparse points can sometimes mimic symlinks but aren't as flexible

Comment: The very first paragraph in that Wikipedia article states "were introduced with the modifications made to the NTFS file system with Windows Vista". The question was about XP.

Comment: Sorry, I had to leave for a meeting and hit save before completing the thought.  I misremembered hard link support in 200+ and Patrick Cuff hit it right on the head.  What's the etiquette?  delete?

Answer (score 0):

Softlinks are supported by the file system used by windows.
Though this functionality is not exposed by any standard windows tools.

There are opensource tools available that can do the trick though.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone seems to be beating around this bush, but I haven't seen anyone actually come out and say it yet: NTFS supports something called "junction points", which are very similar, though slightly less useful than, symlinks.  These are different than both shortcuts and hard links.  I use them regularly for building different versions of our software at the same location on my system (just repoint the build directory link to a different SVN checkout).  The tool I use for this is called [ntfslink](http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink).  That page also contains a pretty good explanation of how NTFS junction points work and which versions of Windows support which features.  I use it on Win Server 2k3.  The ntfslink program is a shell extension, but there are other similar utilities that work from the command line.  There are also Windows API functions available to create them if you want to do it programmatically from whatever app you're developing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this EXACTLY answers the question, but it sure makes life easier!

Go to where the program's installed.  Create a shortcut to the .EXE or startup file. Put the shortcut on the desktop so you know where it is! Then drag the shortcut to the START button (in XP). When the START menu appears, drop it ABOVE the little line (so it stays visible). Hey presto - an instantly created .LNK file with Windows doing all the work for you (yes this DOES work, I've just this second done it/worked it out when I read the question here.)

Comment: The OP needs a commandline way, so that it can be used from a BAT file or something. Manual way is good, but not on the topic.