# am i set an icon to shortcut with mklink cmd command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd

i use on command line on windows and write this.

```
mklink /D programName c:\program files\my app\program.exe
```

but i did not set any icon to my shortcut.

how do i do this?

Answer (score 2):

mklink creates a link, not a shortcut.

If you want to create a shortcut from a batch file, you have several options, see [creating a shortcut for a exe from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

no, i found xxmklink.exe program after that. I am sorry.

http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy38.htm

this is my choice.