# How to create shortcut icon using BATCH file which run my Java application?

Tags: windows, windows-7, vbscript, batch-file

I have a windows.bat file which is actually my custom installer. When everything is installed i finally need to create one desktop shortcut icon, which has icon, and link to execute my Java jar. I successfully made one but its using VBS, what i am trying to do now is avoid using VBS but do it completely using BATCH file only. But how do i make this following in BATCH file?

Example:

[image]

1) Create an empty file vbs.vbs and paste this code to desktop

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersDesktop" ) 
set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop & "\StackOverflow shortcut.lnk") 
oShellLink.TargetPath = "c:\application folder\application.exe" 
oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1 
oShellLink.IconLocation = "c:\application folder\application.ico" 
oShellLink.Description = "Shortcut Script" 
oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = "c:\application folder" 
oShellLink.Save
```

2) Double click the the vbs.vbs file and instantly it creates a shortcut file
in the desktop tested in Windows XP works

But how do i skip the VBS process and do it completely from my BATCH script? 
(Is there any way using `RUNDLL32.EXE APPWIZ.CPL,NewLinkHere (Dest)`)

Comment: do you want it to work for Windows XP upwards?

Comment: @rene: Windows XP, Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8. I want to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was asked and answered before here:

[creating a shortcut for a exe from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file)

One of the provided answers (not the accepted one) has this link:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/amb_shortcutsnt.php

The relevant script is:

```
@echo off & setlocal
::For Windows NT 4.0 users only!!!
::Creates LNK and PIF files from the command line.
::Author: Walter Zackery
if not %1[==[ if exist %1 goto start
echo You must pass the path of a file or folder to the
echo batch file as a shortcut target.
if not %1[==[ echo %1 is not an existing file or folder
(pause & endlocal & goto:eof)
:start
(set hkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows)
(set hkey=%hkey%\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders)
(set inf=rundll32 setupapi,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall)
start/w regedit /e %temp%\#57#.tmp "%hkey%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%? in (
'dir/b/a %1? 2^>nul') do (set name=%%~nx?)

for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%? in (
'findstr/b /i """desktop"""= %temp%\#57#.tmp') do (set d=%%?)

for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%? in (
'findstr/b /i """programs"""= %temp%\#57#.tmp') do (set p=%%?)

(set d=%d:\\=\%) & (set p=%p:\\=\%)
if not %2[==[ if exist %~fs2\nul (set d=%~fs2)
if not %2[==[ if exist %~fs2nul (set d=%~fs2)
set x=if exist %2\nul
if not %2[==[ if not %d%==%2 %x% if "%~p2"=="\" set d=%2
echo %d%|find ":\" >nul||(set d=%d%\)
(set file=""""""%1"""""")
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%? in ("%file:"=%") do set drive=%%?
(set progman=setup.ini, progman.groups,,)
echo > %temp%\#k#.inf [version]
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf signature=$chicago$
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf [DefaultInstall]
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf UpdateInis=Addlink
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf [Addlink]
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf %progman% ""group200="}new{"""
echo >>%temp%\#k#.inf setup.ini, group200,, """%name%"",%file%
start/w %inf% 132 %temp%\#k#.inf
del %temp%\#k#.inf %temp%\#57#.tmp
move %p%\"}new{\*.*" %d% >nul 2>&1
rd %p%\}new{ 2>nul
move %p%\}new{.lnk %d%\"drive %drive%.lnk" >nul 2>&1
endlocal
```

Not sure if that will fly all the way into Win7 and 8

Comment: Is there a solution available for creating shortcuts on Windows 7?

Comment: since it specifically said _For Windows NT 4.0 users only!!!_ I didn't giv a try to it but instead found a solution at [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/43230-make-shortcuts-using-batch-file.html) 
will check it as well if this doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to write the correct script, because no solution works for me
You will need two fileLocal Settings\
first

> createSCUT.bat

```
@echo on
set VBS=createSCUT.vbs 
set SRC_LNK="shortcut1.lnk"
set ARG1_APPLCT="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
set ARG2_APPARG="--profile-directory=QuteQProfile 25QuteQ"
set ARG3_WRKDRC="C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application"
set ARG4_ICOLCT="%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 28\Google Profile.ico"
cscript %VBS% %SRC_LNK% %ARG1_APPLCT% %ARG2_APPARG% %ARG3_WRKDRC% %ARG4_ICOLCT%
```

and second

> createSCUT.vbs

```
Set objWSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objWSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If WScript.arguments.count = 5 then
    WScript.Echo "usage: makeshortcut.vbs shortcutPath targetPath arguments workingDir IconLocation"
    sShortcut = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    set objSC = objWSHShell.CreateShortcut(sShortcut) 
    sTargetPath = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
    sArguments = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))
    sWorkingDirectory = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(3))
    sIconLocation = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(4))
    objSC.TargetPath = sTargetPath
    rem http://www.bigresource.com/VB-simple-replace-function-5bAN30qRDU.html#
    objSC.Arguments = Replace(sArguments, "QuteQ", Chr(34))
    rem http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f63200h0(v=vs.90).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5(v=vs.90).aspx
    objSC.WorkingDirectory = sWorkingDirectory
    objSC.Description = "Love Peace Bliss"
    rem 1 restore 3 max 7 min
    objSC.WindowStyle = "3"
    rem objSC.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Alt+e";
    objSC.IconLocation = sIconLocation
    objSC.Save
    WScript.Quit
end If
If WScript.arguments.count = 4 then
    WScript.Echo "usage: makeshortcut.vbs shortcutPath targetPath arguments workingDir "

    sShortcut = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    set objSC = objWSHShell.CreateShortcut(sShortcut) 
    sTargetPath = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
    sArguments = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(2))
    sWorkingDirectory = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(3))
    objSC.TargetPath = sTargetPath
    objSC.Arguments = Replace(sArguments, "QuteQ", Chr(34))
    objSC.WorkingDirectory = sWorkingDirectory
    objSC.Description = "Love Peace Bliss"
    objSC.WindowStyle = "3"
    objSC.Save
    WScript.Quit
end If
If WScript.arguments.count = 2 then
    WScript.Echo "usage: makeshortcut.vbs shortcutPath targetPath"
    sShortcut = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
    set objSC = objWSHShell.CreateShortcut(sShortcut) 
    sTargetPath = objWSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
    sWorkingDirectory = objFso.GetAbsolutePathName(sShortcut)
    objSC.TargetPath = sTargetPath
    objSC.WorkingDirectory = sWorkingDirectory
    objSC.Save
    WScript.Quit
end If
```