# how to code an C# exe to point to an config file in a different location

Tags: c#, console, directory, app-config, configurationmanager

How would I go about coding my C# console program to look to a different directory for its app.config file?  I would like the config file to sit in the program files folder but have the exe inside the startup folder.

Comment: What you want to do is possible, but can I ask why your executable is in the startup folder and not next to the app.config in the Program Files folder? The startup folder should contain a shortcut to your application, not the executable itself.

Comment: I would love to have a shortcut in the startup folder instead but I need that shortcut to be made and placed there automatically once the user runs my install.bat (which just moves files from network location to client machine) and I have had no luck trying to figure that out.  All in all we are shooting for KISS. ;)

Comment: Try this question / answer, http://stackoverflow.com/q/346107/17776

Comment: @SteveAnselment: IMO, KISS would have more value being applied the other way around (make it simpler for the users). It would be better to do as I suggested because that's the *expected norm*. You get shortcuts on the start menu and application files together in one place. There's a good thread about how to go about creating shortcuts, and it's pretty simple: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file

Comment: @jac: Thank you so much.  I have looked for what seemed like forever trying to find a post just like that one.

Comment: @Cory: It seems great minds think alike!! You gave me the same link as **jac** :)  That is what I will go with then.  Thanks again to both of you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new application domain, and configure it to use configuration file other than default one. Here is how to create and configure app domain :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8hk0245.aspx.

Here is config file property.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx

After you created a domain you can invoke DoCallBack on the created app domain http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.docallback.aspx to start your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input and I am going to mark this as my answer because this is originaly what i asked for but I am going to go with **Cory's** suggestion from above as it is the _expected norm_ for my situation.  CHEERS and Happy Coding!!