# Create shortcut in Bat or VBS

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have been struggeling with creating shortcuts for my program/batch file...
I want to do it in batch, creating a VBS file doing it, since (at least I think) batch can't create shortcuts... But since I am not *at all* familiare with VBS coding I have no clue how to do it at all.

But I know how I want it to be.
I am kind of looking for a code that I can just put the file name and location in, and it works :3
As I am competely disabled at vbs, I won't understand anything too hard.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you take a look at this, the first result from google for "create shortcut batch" http://superuser.com/questions/455364/how-to-create-a-shortcut-using-a-batch-script ?

Comment: @moffeltje yes I did, but I still do not understand the meaning of the code... Like where to put MY file name and MY location :3
Sorry if I didnt make that clear :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346107/creating-a-shortcut-for-a-exe-from-a-batch-file has a few answers that are still relevant today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate this answer for you to understand it;

Make a text file on your desktop and copy/paste this text:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="%TEMP%\%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%-%RANDOM%.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myshortcut.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "D:\myfile.extension" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

Change the `myshortcut.lnk`  in `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myshortcut.lnk"` to the name you want your shortcut to have (for example `"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\iversenFiles.lnk"`).

Change `"D:\myfile.extension"`  to the location you want your shortcut to have (for example `"C:\iversen\Documents\iversen.txt"`).

Save the file and change it's extension from `.txt`  to `.bat`

Double click it.

Comment: When I put pause in th end of the notepad (to see why nothing happened), it gave me: Objektet med navnet "WScript.Shell" kunne ikke oprettes.
Which means: Object with the name "WScript.Shell" could not be created.

...? O,o

Comment: Do you have WScript installed? download link [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8247)

Comment: Oh lol, didnt know it was something you had to download.... But I am not making this for me and my own use only, I am making this for my schools' Smartboards' to automaticly shut down at night. But as the IT security is annoying, I can only create Shortcuts in the windows Startup folder.

So I am meaning for like, every computer to be able to use this, not only people with WScript installed.

Thought it might just be me (my computer) that doesn't have it since it is a RT (Surface 2 Tablet), do you know if regular Windows 7-8 has WScript by default?

Thanks for your help. really appriciate it!

Comment: Could be the case yes, not sure though (and I cannot find proper documentation about it) but you could take a look if `C:\Windows\System32\WScript.exe` is present (if you're able to)

Comment: Looked it up - seems like Windows RT doesn't have it... But again, no "proper documentation" anywhere. But if you got Windows regular 7-8-8.1, got WScript without downloaded first, I am all calm :p

Comment: Hehe, I don't remember installing it or not.. (here says that it's standard installed on W8, 7, Vista and XP)[http://www.whatisdll.com/wscript-exe-repair-free-download-for-windows-78xpvista/]

Comment: Ok. Thanks :) Will try it on my main PC at home. Be back latar

Answer (score 1):

I present a small hybrid script **[BAT/VBS]** to create a desktop shortcut.
So this script shows you how to create a shortcut on the desktop to the calculator.

```
@echo off
mode con cols=87 lines=5 & color 9B
Title Generer le vbscript pour la creation du raccourci sur le bureau by Hackoo
echo Generer le vbscript pour la creation du raccourci
Timeout /T 2 > Nul
(
echo Call Shortcut("c:\windows\system32\calc.exe","Calculatrice"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(CheminApplication,Nom^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split^(CheminApplication,"\"^)
echo    If Nom = "" Then
echo    Nom = MyTab(UBound^(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Nom ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote^(CheminApplication^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "Winver.exe,0"
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr^(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
) > Shortcutme.vbs
echo Execution du vbscript pour la creation du raccourci de la calculatrice sur le bureau
Start /Wait Shortcutme.vbs
echo Suppression du Vbscript
Del Shortcutme.vbs
echo Termine
Pause > Nul
```